# JSP compile error: Arrays cannot be resolved

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

My environment is JDK 1.6, Eclipse Indigo, JBoss 4.2.3.GA-jdk6.

In Eclipse *Windows --> Preferences*, then in *Java --> Compiler* section the ***Compiler compliance level*** is set to **1.6**.

In one JSP I am importing java.util.Arrays.

`<%@ page import="java.util.Arrays"%>`

And then I am using a method of `java.util.Arrays` class:

```
<%
String[] factors = null;

factors = request.getParameterValues("factor");

System.out.println("factors=" + Arrays.toString(factors));
%>
```

When I run it I get the following error messages:

> The import java.util.Arrays cannot be resolved.

and

> Arrays cannot be resolved

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the properties of the Eclipse Project itself.

The ***Java Compiler*** section had ***Enable project specific settings*** checked and its ***Compiler compliance level*** was set to **1.5**. I changed it to **1.6**.

The ***Project Facets*** section had ***Java*** set to **1.5**. I changed it to **1.6**.

Recompile and run and this time no erros.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  According to the javadocs, the `java.util.Arrays` class has been in Java since 1.2, and the `toString(type[])` methods since 1.5.   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Correct, it should have worked. To test I created a new Web project, set its Java to 1.5, wrote the same code in a JSP, deploy the project to same Jboss and tested and it worked. So not sure why it did not work in my original case.

Comment: .... Which suggests to me that the compiler / facets levels weren't what the problem was.  For example, maybe your Eclipse just needed something to poke it into refreshing / rebuilding something.

Comment: It is an old enterprise application and its both EJB and Web modules were set to Java 1.5. I can see in the JSPs in the comments that previous programmers were printing the arrays by looping through them instead of using `Arrays.toString(Object[])` so they must have had the same issue as I was having.